# Abnormal Program Termination In A Turbo C++ Web Browser

Tags: html-parsing, turbo-c++

I've been trying to make a workable web browser in Turbo C++ (I can't help it; I am supposed to work within the confines of my educational system). Essentially, what I have created is a simple parser that takes in a HTML file scans the text for tag delimiters, then identifies the tag, processes it using Turbo C++ default graphics library and then perform the required operation before outputting through an interface I created.

Essentially, I've been matching the cases in a long list of nested conditions. The problem is that execution has been falling through and for some reason I've been continuously getting the error of Abnormal Program Termination.

What I wanted to understand is *why* execution is falling through. Moreover, what does that error truly mean?

[Here's the entire source code.](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1r_0mkcQfKd29yJy32Khbq37APh6xrZGSYqs_JFBBweU)

P.S. - This is my first time on Stack Overflow so if anything is undefined, hazy or plain ridiculous then please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend figured out what went wrong in the code. It turns out that pointer wasn't initialized to null and that caused a sort of cascading failure leading to the abnormal program termination error. Lesson learned.